# Find recursively relative paths without showing the main directory contents

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, find

First of all... I'm newbie in linux! haha
I'm trying to show all the files and directories from a main directory but I need to exclude the main directory record.

Example (all files in `/var/www/html`):

1. index.php
2. **Images**
3. Images/1.jpg
4. Images/2.jpg
5. Images/3.jp3
6. **Includes**
7. Includes/db.php
8. Includes/security.php

The records that I want to exclude I've shown in bold / strong

Now I'm using this command:
`find /var/www/html/ -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\n'`

I appreciate any help. Regards!

Comment: If you need to  include only files, use `-type f`

Comment: You should use `-mindepth 2` instead of `-mindepth 1` to ignore files/dirs that are directly under `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: this works fine! genius! thanks a lot!